# Which statistical analysis to use to prove a process outputs the same results each time it runs

Tags: anova, inference, ancova

It's the first time I have to do a statistical analysis for a college project and I'm pretty confused.

I want to verify if a process produces reliably the same output every time it runs.

A "run" consists of starting with one server, measuring the output, adding another server, measuring the output etc.

If the process is run multiple times, the output should always approximately be the same.

How do I statistically describe this? Is there any test I can do to say the graphs produced by each measurement are not statistically significantly different?

Here is an example image: 
[image]

I've read up on Repeated Measures ANOVA, ANCOVA and Test-Retest-Reliability, but I'm unsure which one to use, if any.

Thanks so much for any hints!